# не получается сделать запуск файла nodejs

Tags: node.js

Пишет ошибка когда хочешь запустить скрипт из директории nodejs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `node /mozilla-festival/game.js` - сам вызов, а папка `node_modules` должна быть там же, где `game.js`

Comment: `node_modules` в родительской директории - в целом, допустимый случай, хотя и не совсем обычный

Comment: @NumminorihSF допустимы, если модули установлены глобально. У автора неясно так оно или нет.

Comment: Наличие проблемы с модулями не определено.) Нода не находит целевой скрипт. Модули нпма в родительских директориях - допустимо, хотя бы из за того, как работает `require`

Answer (score 1):

Уберите ведущий слеш перед директорией файла

Т.е. нужно запускать `nodejs path/to/file.js`. js в конце можно опустить